# google maps api conflicting with a div with background-attachment:fixed which overlaps it

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3

I have a DIV with a background-attachment: fixed and another DIV further down the page with position:fixed.  This is working fine in IE11 and Firefox 31.0 but in in Chrome the div with background-attachment: fixed is scrolling the image with the DIV and has large black blocks across the image's full width, sometimes covering half the image, sometimes in thick bars (like a zebra if you will)

If I don't run the google map JS, or have background-attachment: scroll, or have position: static, then all works as you would expect.

Am I doing something wrong, is this a bug in Chrome? either way I need to find a way to make it behave as intended (fixed background image and fixed google maps div to window) - so either a correction of my code, or a workaround for a 'bug' would be really helpful.

(aside: I also have a fixed DIV at the top for a nav bar but it isn't affecting the issue.  I believe this is because it does not stack with the google map)

code in full:  http://jsfiddle.net/chowie/rodx0v02/3/

HTML:

```
<div id="hobbiescontainer"  class="sectioncontainer">          
    <section id="hobbiesSection">    
        <a id="hobbies"><h4>Hobbies</h4></a>                    
        <p class="keytext">
        text content here
        </p>
    </section>
</div>

<div id="mapcontainer">
    <div id="map"></div>   
</div>

<div id="mapspace"></div>
```

CSS:

```
section {
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
overflow:auto;
padding: 0px;
}
```

JS:

```
function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5028397, -0.2521218),
    zoom: 15
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
    mapOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5028397, -0.2521218),
    map: map,
    icon: image,
});
}
```

Comment: I don't see a map on your fiddle.

Comment: Do they usually? Not sure if I've set it up wrong. Is normally there.  The fiddle output doesn't accurately reflect the problem anyway, maybe because the background image and map aren't there.

Comment: A fiddle that doesn't demonstrate the issue is not all that useful. A [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance @geocodezip - have updated my fiddle and now demonstrates the problem http://jsfiddle.net/chowie/rodx0v02/3/

Comment: @Chowie did you ever get a fix for this? I just ran into the same issue and saw this post

Comment: @Chowie I also have this issue, any solutions?

Comment: Sadly no not yet.  I think I just stopped trying to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google maps ads an inline style of `transform: translateZ(0px);` to your map container via javascript (which as far as I can tell does nothing whatsoever). Overriding it with `transform: inherit !important;` in my stylesheet fixed this for me.